# how to call delegate

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
public class Test
{
  public static long Method1(Action a)
  {
        var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        a.Invoke();
        s.Stop();
        return s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
  }
}
```

in another class
how I am trying to call this

```
            double elapsed = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {


                elapsed+= (TestHelper.Timer(() => session.SaveTransaction(transaction)));
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("avg execution time is {0} ms", elapsed/100000));
```

which does not compile. How should the call code be?

Comment: That's clearly not your *real* code or it wouldn't compile. It's Milliseconds, not Miliseconds, and Stopwatch, not StopWatch.

Comment: I prefer calling `a()` over `a.Invoke()`. Same thing however :)

Comment: and I usually as a best practice don't copy paste my code , I just try to describe the issue. So I really don't get your negative vote.

Comment: @Elena: No, best practice *is* to copy/paste code. Not necessarily your *original* code, but a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Your elapsed variable is of type *double*, not Action.

Comment: Please show TestHelper.Timer. Basically, a short but complete progra, which actually demonstrates the problem, instead of snippets which won't compile, use different methods etc.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

- You're measuring a *single invocation*; generally you should time *lots* of invocations, as otherwise it's likely to be too quick to measure (or at least under a millisecond).
- You're using `TimeSpan.Milliseconds` when you probably actually mean `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`; otherwise if you've got over a second, it'll still report a value between 0 and 999.

Comment: it is contained in a for loop but i was too lazy to copy paste, but still if I have for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {miliseconds = Test.Method1(delegate {whichever method needs to be measured})} it does not compile saying double does not contain an extension method for TotalMiliseconds

Comment: @Elena: No, you loop *inside* the method, invoking the delegate many times. Otherwise you're just going to be adding 0 lots of times. That's not going to help. As always, a short but *complete* program demonstrating the *real* problem is a good idea.

Comment: maybe I am just tired, but what does you "loop inside the method" mean? argghh, got it. ok thanks

Comment: @Elena: Currently the comment shows you looping and calling `Test.Method` lots of times. Move that loop *inside* `Test.Method`, inside the stopwatch block - so you start the stopwatch, invoke the delegate lots of times, *then* stop the stopwatch.